# How to get value with JXPathContext if xmlns specified?

Tags: java, xml

```
final SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
final Document xml = builder.build( file );
final Element root = (Element) xml.getRootElement();
Element child = root.getChild("Header", Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.editeur.org/icedis/claims"));
final XPathContext ctx = XPathContext.create(root);
```

This is the code I have. XPathContext is just wrapper around JXPathContext. As you see, 'child' variable using construction with Namespace and it won't work if I remove it.

But now I'm trying to get value from XML with XPath like this

```
ctx.getValue("/Header/SentDateTime")
```

And, ofcourse it always return null. It seems that solution is simple, but I can't find it in the internet. If I delete xmlns from XML file, everything will work, but this isn't an option. So how should I work with this xml?

Also, short version of XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ICEDISClaimMessage version="0.1" xmlns="http://www.editeur.org/icedis/claims">
    <Header>
        <Sender>
            <SenderIdentifier>
                <SenderIDType>06</SenderIDType>
                <IDValue>1234567890128</IDValue>
            </SenderIdentifier>
            <SenderName>Apogee Agency</SenderName>
        </Sender>
        <Addressee>
            <AddresseeIdentifier>
                <AddresseeIDType>06</AddresseeIDType>
                <IDValue>2345678901237</IDValue>
            </AddresseeIdentifier>
        </Addressee>
        <MessageNumber>111</MessageNumber>
        <SentDateTime>20101001</SentDateTime>
        <MessageNote>Sample file 1: a claim made by an agent to a publisher for a journal issue not yet delivered</MessageNote>
    </Header>
</<ICEDISClaimMessage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an XPath expression with a namespace context. It would have to look something like this:

```
final XPathContext ctx = XPathContext.create(root);
ctx.addNamespaceMapping("ns", "http://www.editeur.org/icedis/claims");
... = ctx.getValue("/ns:Header/ns:SentDateTime");
```

NB: I don't know whether JXPath supports namespaces, and if it does, how it is set up.

And, by the way, it looks like you are using JDOM (SAXBuilder). In that case I would recommend using the JDOM built in XPath functions instead of building a wrapper.